# Why does authorization grant flow skip the authorization code just return an access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm learning about O Auth 2 from [here](http://www.binarywebpark.com/oauth-2-tutorial/)

[image]

I was wondering in the step of "Authorization server redirects user agent to client with authorization code", why doesn't the server just give the access token instead? Why give an authorization code that then is used to get the access token? Why not just give the access token directly? Is it because there there is a different access token for each resource so that you need to go through O Auth again to access a different resource?

Answer (score 0):

The authorization grant code can pass through unsecured or potentially risky environments such as basic HTTP connection (not HTTPS) or a browser. But it's worthless without a client secret. The client can be a backend application. If the OAuth2 server returned a token, it could get compromised.

There is another OAuth2 flow - the [Implicit flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-31), which returns an access token right after the authentication, but it's designed mainly for JavaScript applications or other deployments where it's safe to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If a malicious app gets hold of the client id of your app(which is easily available, for example one can inspect the source), then it can use that to retrieve the token without the use of the client secret. All the malicious app needs to do is to somehow either specify the redirect URI to itself or to tap into the registered redirect URI.

That is the reason for breaking the flow as such. Note, when the client secret is not to be used as in SPA (Single Page Apps) or Mobile Apps, then PKCE comes to the rescue.

There is a reason for breaking up the authorization flow so as to keep the resource owner's interaction with the authorization server isolated from the client's interactions with the authorization server. Therefore we need to have two interactions with the authorization server. One in which the resource owner authenticates with it's credentials to the authorization server. And another where the client sends in it's client secret to the authorization server.

Please also see [PKCE](https://oauth.net/2/pkce/) that deals with SPA (SinglePageApp)/Mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain this more straightforwardly: these 2 steps have entirely different responsibilities

- the step of getting the auth code is responsible for user (human) authentication (ex., when you enter login/pass), in which an insecure browser passes some params to the auth server. We literally can't send any secrets here as there is no secured backend, so everything is exposed, and `client_id` can be whatever we want
- the step of swapping the auth code for an access token is where our secured backend requests the auth server, and the authenticated user here is just a param. In another way, the machine talks to the machine via a secured layer so we can finally send our secret and verify the `client-secret` pair

So, in our case, it's 2 actions for 2 different "checks": check that the user is who he is, then check that the backend machine is what it is.

Without a backend, we indeed need to check only a user and so have a token right away in a single step. This is called implicit flow.